# Store notifications from a Metro Style App

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm implementing notifications into my app, but I am trying to figure out what I need to do to know if a Channel is an "Update" vs a "New" channel that wants to receive notifications.

Currently, everytime the app is ran, it sends me the new channel and the expire date.  When I want to send a new notification, I am going to assume everyday, I'll get a new one of these for the same person.  I need a way to only send it to the person once.

I was thinking about using CoreApplication.Id and store that, but I am not sure if that is unique per application install.

Any ideas how to go about this?  I have read several articles, but they are all just showing how to push it once, no mention to this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want it to be stored? Just run-time or do you want to have a local file ?

Comment: I just need something that would signify if the Channel sent to the server is an update or a new.  The server stores the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add another aspect of identification in your service. Because the URI can change any time, and there maybe multiple installs of your client, you will have some challenges trying to identify unique per user notifications without having identified some "user" id uniquely.

Likely, you want to take advantage of either:

- Microsoft Account, using this to identify the user
- Make the client application get a "unique" identifier for your client from your server (it could just be a GUID), and save that in roam settings. This will travel with the client across machines. If it's there, clearly it's not a new customer.

Note that if the user uninstalls your app on ALL their machines/accounts, then the roaming setting may go away. This is an undefined period of time.

Comment: Do you know of a way to automatically get the Microsoft Account?  Only thing I found gets the First Name, Last Name, etc...  Nothing in there gave me the Microsoft Account.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.onlineid.useridentity.id.aspx is probably a good place to start. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.onlineid.useridentity.aspx has the details to get an instance. IMHO, the latter option i provided is way simpler, and doesn't require you to authenticate the user in windows either.